# Redirected Too Many Times on Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache2, html, www

I'm using apache2 to host a website on Ubuntu Server. When I try to load the page from a browser, I get the "this page redirected you too many times" error. I don't have any duplicate files or anything that's redirecting the page. I don't have a `.htaccess` file because this is not a WordPress project. If anyone could help, it'd be very appreciated!

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr note
```

Comment: Your DocumentRoot needs a leading forward slash in front of it, ie `/var/www/html`

Comment: WordPress is not the only application using .htaccess. Check if you really have one. Additionally, redirects can occur on more levels than just Apache, they can also be generated by the application being served. Check your application (whatever it is). You can get more clues by looking at the access logs of your webserver and by running a text based HTTP client (`wget -S`, `curl`) or by looking at the response headers in the developer tools of your browser, use them to see what redirects you actually get.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I don't have a `.htaccess` file anywhere. The response headers say "No content available because this request was redirected".

Comment: @tilleyc I added a `/` in `/var/www/html`, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Well, if this really is the only configuration file involved then the redirect is not coming from Apache. But an Apache config usually consists of many files. You can find out which configuration files contains which VirtualHost by running `apache2ctl -S`.